# Eclipse doesn't recognize already existent projects I'm attempting to import and improperly imports projects?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse Indigo and I'm using it for the purpose of developing Android mobile apps. I'm attempting to import the new version of the ActionBarSherlock library to use with a project I've already got. I've tried to go to **File > Import... > Existing Projects** but that doesn't find anything and I've also tried doing **File > New > Android Project > From existing source** but it only imports like half the resources folder and that's about it. It doesn't import any other files and it even leaves out the AndroidManifest.xml file which is obviously a key file here. 
 Any help out there for me or am I stuck? :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the jar into your `/workspace/<appname>/libs` folder. Go back into Eclipse, right-click on your project and choose refresh (verify that a new folder appears in your project). Next, go into Menu->Project->Properties [Java Build Path]. Choose Libraries tab then [Add Jars...] and finally browse to your libs folder. Your new jar should be available.

Comment: ActionBarSherlock is a library and because of certain dependencies it relies on, it cannot be built into a .jar file which means what you said won't work for my problem. :-/

Comment: You'll have to add the project folder/path to your project and then add the uses-lib tag in your manifest file. I'll add another "answer".

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add that library as an external library and then reference it in your manifest file similar to how we implement the GoogleAPI for maps.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

If that doesn't so it the next thing I'd try is to copy/paste that project under your apps project folder. You'll have to go into that project and resolve the "package" names to reflect your own package names. Once you do that, all those classes will be visible in your project. You may need to manually merge resources if there are conflicts.

Comment: I'll have to try that. In the meantime, I'm going to be attempting to use IntelliJ as I've heard it is better in the long run because you don't have to deal with a lot of the Android and ADT related bugs that Eclipse causes. I'll report back with what I choose to do and my results.